# What is this rubber strip dangling below the car?

Tags: part-identification

[image: dangling rubber strip]
[image]

The car is a 2016 Fiat Panda, and there is a rubber-like strip dangling from a beam near the middle of the front axle. What is this and what it's purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an aftermarket grounding strap. It is supposed to help prevent static electricity from collecting in your car. In reality, they don't help much of anything. They used to be *very common* back in the day, but now have gone out of favor. This is not really needed and looks ugly besides. If you loosen the "C" clamp portion, this thing will fall off and you can get rid of it if you like.

Comment: Where I live in the UK they have been sold for decades. Often these have a design on them of a lightning flash; they are often sold as a way of 'preventing' car sickness. Also people attached a length of light chain to drag along the road.